# Large Arrays of dataType String

Tags: java, arrays, iostream

I hope everyone is doing okay.  I'm still new to this developer stuff, and although I find it really interesting I'm beginning to see how it can get tedious if you don't keep track of what you are doing.  Im working on an update for a mock ATM program.  The new version reads from a .txt file to validate account information.  Once it is validated you can either check the balance, deposit money, withdrawal money, or log out.  Once you do your transaction, the program is suppose to update the old .txt file with the updated balance for that account.  I finally got everything to work like it is suppose to, but when I go back and check the updated .txt file, that particular account was updated but the rest of the strings in the file were updated to null and I can't figure out why and what is causing my program to do that.  I have a feeling that the problem is in the upDate method and I'm overlooking something.  Below you can see my source code and below the output of what I am getting.  Any explanation about the logic behind this error would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ATM2 {

    public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    /*
     * This method reads the number of lines in the .txt file
     * and returns the array size.
     */
    public static int arraySize () {
        int result = 0;
        try 
        {
            Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(new FileReader("ATMData.txt"));
            int lineCount=0;

            while(lineReader.hasNextLine())
            {
                String size;
                size = lineReader.nextLine();
                lineCount++;
            }
            lineReader.close();
            return lineCount;

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR:  FILE NOT FOUND");
            return result;
        }
    }

    //Method searches .txt file and returns String
    //array with all account info.
    public static String[] acctLine(int size){

        String[] validAccounts = null;
        try 
        {
            Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(new FileReader("ATMData.txt"));
            int lineCount=0;
            String [] acctNums= new String[size];

            while(lineReader.hasNextLine())
            {
                String lineInfo;
                lineInfo = lineReader.nextLine();
                acctNums[lineCount]=lineInfo;
                lineCount++;
            }
            lineReader.close();
            return acctNums;
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: FILE NOT FOUND");
            return validAccounts;
        }
    }

    //Method updates the txt file with new acct information.
    public static void acctUpdate (String[] validAccount, String fileName){

        try
        {
            PrintWriter newFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
            for(int i=0; i<validAccount.length; i++){
                newFile.println(validAccount[i]);
            }
            newFile.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR:  FILE NOT PRINTED");
        }

    }

    /*The checkID method determines if acctNum is a valid account number
     * and pwd is the correct password for the account.  If the account information
     * is valid, the method returns the current account balance, as a string.
     * If the account information is invalid, the method returns the string "error"
     */
    public static String checkID(String acctNum, String pwd, String [] validAccounts)
    {

        String result = "ERROR";
        String acctString = "ERROR";

        boolean foundIt = false;

        for(int i=0; i<validAccounts.length; i++)  //Loop compares the input data with array data.
        {   
            acctString = validAccounts[i];
            if (acctNum.equals(acctString.substring(0, acctString.indexOf(" "))) && 
                    pwd.equals(acctString.substring(acctString.indexOf(" ")+1,acctString.lastIndexOf(" ")))){
                foundIt = true;
                result = acctString.substring(acctString.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
            }
        }

        if (foundIt) //If it's true it returns the acct. balance.
        {
            return result;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR:  INVALID ACCOUNT TYPE"); 
        }
        return result;
    }

    /* This method finds the array index of the desired account string.
     *  and returns the the index of the line
     */
    public static int arrayIndex(String acctNum, String pwd, String [] validAccounts)
    {
        int accountPos=0;

        Boolean foundIt = false;
        //loop searches for the index of the array.
        for(accountPos=0; accountPos<validAccounts.length && !foundIt; accountPos++)
        {   
            if (acctNum.equals(validAccounts[accountPos].substring(0, validAccounts[accountPos].indexOf(" "))) && 
                    pwd.equals(validAccounts[accountPos].substring(validAccounts[accountPos].indexOf(" ")+1, validAccounts[accountPos].lastIndexOf(" "))))
            {               
                foundIt = true;
            }
        }
        return accountPos;
    }

    /*Method creates menu options and returns
     *the choice selected by the user.
     */
    public static int menu()
    {
        int menuChoice;
        do
        { 
            System.out.print("\nENTER TRANSACTION TYPE: CHOOSE 1-4."
                    + " \n 1. Display Balance"
                    + "\n 2. Deposit\n 3. Withdraw\n 4. Log Out\n");
            menuChoice = kbd.nextInt();
            if (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 4){
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        }while (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 4);

        return menuChoice;
    }

    /*Method displays the balance to the screen.
     */
    public static void displayBalance(double balance)
    {
        System.out.printf("\nYOUR NEW BALANCE IS: $%.2f\n", balance);
    }

    /*Method calculates the deposit going in to account.
    Returns the total deposit.
     */
    public static double deposit(double orgBal, double depAmt)
    {
        return orgBal + depAmt;
    }

    /*Method that calculates the balance after the withdraw.
     * returns a double with the amount withdrawn.
     */
    public static double withdraw(double orgBal, double wdrlAmt)
    {
        if (wdrlAmt > orgBal)
        {
            return orgBal;
        }
        else
        {
            return orgBal-wdrlAmt;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String accNum, pass, fileName="ATMData.txt", origBal = "ERROR";
        String acctInfo;
        int count = 0, menuOption = 0, acctPos;
        double depositAmt, withdrawAmt, currentBal; 
        String [] validAccounts =acctLine(arraySize());

        /*loop that will count the number of login attempts
         *you make and will exit program if it is more than 3.
         *as long as oriBal equals an error.  
         */
        do{

            System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER YOUR ACCOUNT NUMBER: ");
            accNum = kbd.next();

            System.out.println("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD: ");
            pass = kbd.next();

            origBal = checkID(accNum, pass, validAccounts);
            count++;

            acctPos = arrayIndex(accNum, pass, validAccounts)-1;

            if (count >= 3 && origBal.equals("ERROR:")){
                System.out.print("MAX LOGIN ATTEMPTS REACHED.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if (!(origBal.equals("ERROR"))){
                System.out.println("\nYOUR CURRENT BALANCE IS: $ "+ origBal);
            }
            else
                System.out.println(origBal);

        }while(origBal.equals("ERROR"));

        currentBal=Double.parseDouble(origBal);

        /*this loop will keep track of the options that 
         *the user inputs in for the menu. and will 
         *give the option of deposit, withdraw, or logout.
         */
        while (menuOption != 4)
        { 
            menuOption=menu();
            switch (menuOption)
            {
            case 1:
                displayBalance(currentBal);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("HOW MUCH DO WISH TO DEPOSIT: $ ");
                depositAmt = kbd.nextDouble();
                currentBal = deposit(depositAmt, currentBal);
                displayBalance(currentBal);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("HOW MUCH DO YOU WISH TO WITHDRAW: $ ");
                withdrawAmt = kbd.nextDouble();
                if (withdrawAmt > currentBal)
                    System.out.println("ERROR:  YOU DON'T HAVE ENOUGH FUNDS TO COMPLETE"
                            + " TRANSACTION."
                            + " ENTER TRANSACTION TYPE: CHOOSE 1-4");
                currentBal = withdraw(currentBal, withdrawAmt);
                displayBalance(currentBal);
                break;
            case 4://Last option logs user out after it updates the ATMData.txt
                acctInfo = accNum + " " + pass + " " + String.valueOf(currentBal);
                validAccounts[acctPos]=acctInfo;
                acctUpdate(validAccounts, fileName);
                System.out.println("LOGOUT SUCCESSFULL.");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
                default:
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

And this is what the .txt looked like before source code update. The only thing updated is the one line.

```
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
417927608 ;6FYE5l`LPX@ 4101.13
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

Because we are passing by reference we only needed to declare the original array in the main program once. .

```
7560640 6Z[NVoee1S6 4424.43
04569505 f:H>wAr@<URH 4211.42
528859 ][[79_W?]=:< 724.26
973335820 Si>G7QMp?>e 3207.28
79154675 Y>vfTYwHm0J 3327.47
5554284 6n[^PwZUZlH 1028.66
58773836 28vcgSpwA01 3131.02
95873039 @4XwrN`T9 2598.28
1034703 n@HKk`mTar2Z 1176.75
10192851 X>ATvaR:qT 3857.89
417927608 ;6FYE5l`LPX@ 3401.13
143260 s2UgJtSHYFmn 378.68
34729802 rh\<3rmk7Dm< 255.48
277791753 BR2=siCDi 345.75
1014748 PK?KTMjA63e 1196.16
496714922 M1=I`ve;Wjw 501.26
654156 AB`6cvO0ql: 4310.51
898250859 t^D90Nw?Ii 3876.05
971750 [9q_5AuLlJ 135.97
796678134 KwV^03p:WW=< 3453.65
39482807 C5?H?b9UplL 4109.48
401599 MvHL7Yv07bW 4356.96
8321377 Jc:<_ke9B: 930.90
152773 VQ6\[2k:uoj 3265.93
624426519 kralkKKEia3 4858.39
650002 Km2t\R3>3@G 1470.78
004509766 _0S`1qb^V 1332.24
0274647 WDhg3\p]w 3147.50
974502771 Q4GT<_s3D9CK 4464.22
281866 c_1F]@RpV^ 2952.03
381121 rOo?CiA[kwTs 4555.21
1549064 F7^eh=njp\r 430.24
841319 IBe^GTLGv 4050.76
6499423 tW9>r[s_<\ 1418.09
8579740 cdB12UrLU 2905.74
33581232 <os4;WcEqb 2455.32
725175174 nWjIeFLK3E 3118.08
592410029 RqgPT382p2Lk 3863.32
08274516 DDr?^vuNQ 1630.37
808471 Ow:8udlBrYP 2590.05
769854 0`lpWGrMkrG 2643.59
3591827 MmThLS1DdL5 2715.30
9001605 \n;rMknh7C 4074.83
10345766 N>^qBqhk?39J 539.43
504385 j0Rq=li0c^ 253.77
362335041 >^VN5oh?OSR 324.19
5728008 QZ>BZhGEv 4441.67
26102273 1XCWR;W?^b\ 4203.51
3317249 dmjLKbgZ? 1958.44
793249 5J>ApQZAB 1906.46
536461203 CP5U:f5\d[_p 3742.25
030298042 VBtHo909;QM 986.28
6111228 mmPgiDMALt 1348.95
621992 r7UmSJ\9j 1440.22
310072768 B1ccagCH3 4755.56
819894803 IXfcY9PZG1 4399.39
362945795 5LAdX_s^G 3624.28
99929088 `oHijc^J0u 4507.69
821671 s@OV>NYlacV 4125.72
72368663 Mi?wTcZ_@I 2845.24
22692406 uT05^2plu 2530.73
343817 pB;Glu5sVb7P 2168.28
5138360 877<cT4T;t 1562.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never write the previous account data into `validAccounts`.  When you run `String [] validAccounts = new String[arraySize()];` all of the string instances get set to null and only get changed when you update an account.  What you need to do is when you start your program, read the existing text file into that String array and then just change the entries you need to.  When you are done, write the String array to the file.

Answer (score 1):

In your main method
String[] validAccounts = new String[arraySize()];
which means you have an array of NULL values, you need to assign the values data here rather than in another method, as when you pass the array you are passing a reference to this array rather than the data itself
so in arrayIndex
validAccounts = acctLine(arraySize()); will put the data in this method and when it returns this data is discarded. 
You need to assign the data ONCE then pass this around without writing over it in methods

e.g. in main
String[] validAccounts = new String[arraySize()];
should be 
String[] validAccounts = acctLine(arraySize());
You don't need to read it again in arrayIndex or checkID.
So read it once and store it, pass this data to the method and read from this data rather than a new file read

a simple example is this - you'll see the a = new int.... does not change a in original method, but assignment does in doesSomething

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int[] a = {1,2,3};
    doesNothing(a);
    for (int i: a)
        System.out.print(i);
    doesSomething(a);
    for (int i: a)
        System.out.print(i);

}

static void doesNothing(int[] a) {
    a = new int[]{4,5,6};
}

static void doesSomething(int[] a) {
    a[0] = 7;
    a[1] = 8;
    a[2] = 9;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, it worked, and the way you explained the logic error made the adjustment rather simple.  I wish I could get a CS professor that explains and teach it as well.  I have updated the final with the changes.  Although this works for what I was doing, what would you suggest can improve efficiency of the updated code? Again, I'm new to this and I feel that I learn a lot from you gracious contributors.